# Universal version of google play services

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, apk, react-native-maps

I want to use the `react-native-maps` package in my react-native app and this package needs the latest version of google play services to work properly. I want to host an APK of google play services in somewhere and refer the users to download it if the version of their google play services is out of date.I want to know is there any universal version of google play services that is compatible with all android devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think the (030) version of google play services will work on every version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You are trying to use latest/updated version of google-play-services. In `react-native-maps` Maybe they are using updated one. Or I'm assuming they are using out of date one. 
If you want to use updated one first fix that which one you want to use then do like below: skip `react-native-maps` google-play-services version and use your own defined.

```
 compile (project(':react-native-maps')) {
        // exclude version their version
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
//user your own 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:X.x.x'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:X.x.x'
```

Thanks if you have any query you can ask me and for Gradle dependency, you can learn more from [here](https://osmangoni.info/posts/google-play-service-version-incompatibility-react-native/)